# JSX highlighting with Neovim and nvim-treesitter

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, plugin-treesitter

I'm using `Neovim 0.6.0` with [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/navarasu/onedark.nvim) installed and I mostly work with JavaScript, Flow, TypeScript based React projects. This means, I also need syntax highlighting for JSX and TSX.

Syntax highlighting works rather well with TypeScript and TSX out of the box, however, I'm finding that JSX isn't highlighting at all, and some statements are rather bland.

The [navarasu/onedark.nvim](https://github.com/navarasu/onedark.nvim) theme is installed here.

I managed to get around this by installing the following packages:

- [pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript)
- [maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty](https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty)

**Syntax highlighting: Treesitter only**

[image: without extra plugins]

**Syntax highlighting - with extra plugins**

[image: with extra plugins]

Note how the `console.log` on line 7 is looking rather untouched, and also, the JSX syntax is all in gray.

This probably isn't the right way to go. I don't think the above plugins use treesitter under the hood, and I think I might be having multiple syntax highlighers running at the same time, possibly even fighting over coloring the code.

Is there a better way to configure `nvim-treesitter` to work with JSX highlighting, and also get the default JS highlighting a bit richer?

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. This was because I didn't enable the **highlight** module where I called

```
require('nvim-treesitter.configs').setup {}
```

So after fixing, the above call should at least look like this:

```
require('nvim-treesitter.configs').setup {
  highlight = {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the option I was missing in order to highlight properly TypeScript JSX parts in my functional components.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, but I had missed the part where I needed to run

```
:TSInstall typescript
:TSInstall javascript
:TSInstall tsx
```